# What's the type of the first value of `NS_ENUM` actually is?

Tags: objective-c, enums

As we all know ,the `NS_ENUM` is a macro defined by Apple,by which we can easily define a enum type contain a set of value. There are two fact that:

- The type of the value in ENUM is `NSInteger`, actually it is a C-base type.
- A C-base type variable can't pass to a Objective-C type paramter.

Question Description:

I defined a NS_ENUM type contains three value. And I need to use this enum type value as a parameter of a block varable who declear a `id` type. When I passed the first value of the defined enum type as the paramter of block, the complier didn't Tip me anything.
But when I pass the second value of the enum type the complier reported me an error says  **Implicit conversion of 'NSInteger' (aka 'long') to 'id' is disallowed with ARC** and a warning says **Incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'NSInteger' (aka 'long') to parameter of type '__strong id'**.

It means a varable based C-base type can't be conversed to a Objective - C type.

**SO THE QUESTION IS**  why I can pass the first value of but not the second value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define an enum, each enum value is given the next integer value starting with 0. This means that the first enum value has a value of 0, the second has a value of 1, etc.

The reason you can use the first enum value for a parameter of type of `id` is that the compiler actually passes the enum's value (which is 0 for the first enum value). And 0 is really the same thing as `nil`.

In other words, passing the first enum value (a value of 0) is the same as passing `nil`. So the compiler doesn't complain since it's fine to pass `nil`.

But for any other (non-zero) enum value, the compiler sees the `NSInteger` value and correctly complains that you can't pass an `NSInteger` value to a parameter of type `id`.

The proper solution in most (all?) cases is to wrap the enum value as an `NSNumber`. The best way is to use the modern `@( )` syntax for this.

```
SomeEnumType myEnumVariable = SomeEnumValue;
[someInstance someMethod:@(myEnumVariable)];
```

where `someMethod:` expects an `id` object. In this case it will get an `NSNumber` wrapping the enum value.

Of course your `someMethod` must be written to expect the value to be sent this way.

Comment: Also, if the user is calling the method directly, then it can send enum value in it directly without casting it to NSNumber/NSValue. But blocks always carry object type as their parameters.

Comment: @AnkitThakur I agree with your answer, but not all of it.

Comment: @rmaddy Sorry,your answer helped me a lot Thx.@AnkitThakur said that block carry object type, I don't understand what it means.Is there any sample?

Comment: @lynulzy I'm not sure what Ankit is referring to.